# Value index is not specified for an option - Magento 2 API

Tags: magento2, attributes, api, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I'm getting the error at below, when i try to set the configurable attribute, to create configurable product via Magento 2 API:

as described in: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/define-config-product-options.html

```
{"message":"Value index is not specified for an option."}
```

my code is:

```
$sampleProductData = array(

'option' => array(
    'attribute_id' => 150, 
    'label' => 'Shoe Size',
    'position' => 0,
    'is_use_default' => true,
    'values' => array(
        'value_index' => '8' ),
), );

$productData = json_encode($sampleProductData);
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

150 is 'Shoe Size' attribute ID, and 8 is the shoe size 37's ID

Answer (score 0):

There is missing an extra array around the value_index:

```
$sampleProductData = [
   'option' => [
      'attribute_id' => 150, 
      'label' => 'Shoe Size',
      'position' => 0,
      'is_use_default' => true,
      'values' => [
          [
            'value_index' => 8
          ]
      ]
   ]
];
```

Official docs:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/define-config-product-options.html#set-the-configurable-attribute